# scale free drawing inside the canvas of html5

Tags: html, html5-canvas

i'm just wondering if this is possible: say you have a drawing app that works with HTML5 canvas... if you just say.. draw a few lines and squiggles. could you then scale the image as if it were a vector(mathematically stored) image like inscape?

Comment: You can scale the entire canvas, yes. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#scale());

Comment: would that scale everything that is inside the canvas? Such as something someone drew?

Comment: I assumed it would, but it seems that scale only affects things drawn to the canvas after it is set.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about scalable vector grapichs, or SVG.

You can find a lot of SVG libraries for JavaScript, which makes this pretty easy, if you do not want to do all the plumbing yourself.  [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) is such a library.

Comment: well to be specific what I want is a program like paint... where a user can draw an image. Then I want to send that image to someone else... and the person who gets it might have a smaller or larger canvas because of their screen resolution. So the image should get scaled accordingly keeping the proportions

Comment: svg-edit (http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) looks quite impressive.  I guess you could get some ideas from it.